# How to limit the execution time in C

Tags: c, time, limit, execution

I'm not a big C expert, and that's why I ask this (probably) easy question.
I got a script written in C, and I'd like to limit the execution time with input.

Like:
./script.c input1 input2 input3 input4

Input4 has to be the time limit in seconds.

In php, it would be something like this:

```
$_GET['time'] = $time;
```

`max_execution_time($time);` or `set_time_limit($time)`
And then I would run it like this: http://domain.com/script.php?time=60

I think that `init_rand(time(NULL));` should work for the time limiting but how can I take the variable from the "GET" (input4)?

Comment: C# is not C please correct your tags

Comment: What do you mean by limiting the execution time?

Answer (score 3):

May be you can run this program as a child of another program.

```
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    exit(1);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    execvp("this prog", argv);
} else  {
    sleep(atoi(argv[4]);
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
}
```

Or may be you can use bash scripts to do the job.

```
./thisprog $1 $2 $3 &
sleep $4 
kill $! 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I would like to code it in the same script, I've checked out other scripts, and gathered this: init_rand(time(NULL));

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are compiling in Linux using `GCC` as follows,

```
gcc ./a.out input1 input2 input3 input 4
```

You can use the function `setrlimit()` to set limits.

The following code directly calls the `ulimit` command from the C Program,

```
system(ulimit -t TIME_LIMIT);
```

If you want to set user defined limit, then the following code might help you,

```
int i;
char com[100];

i=atoi(argv[4]);

sprintf(com,"ulimit -t %d",i);
system(com);
```